# Не работает пример из книги javascript

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript по книге "Ajax и php разработка динамических веб приложений". Написал пример по книге, но он не работает, google chrome пишет при нажатии кнопки

> csstest.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null
>       at setStyle1 (csstest.js:8)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (csstest.html:28)

Исходники ниже:
Файл csstest.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Основы Ajax</title>
 <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="csstest.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 <table id="table>
 <tr>
  <th id="tableHead">
  Название продукта
  </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="tableFirstLine">
  Самолет
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="tableSecondLine">
  Автомобиль
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <br />
 <input type="button" value="Стиль 1" onclick="setStyle1();" />
 <input type="button" value="Стиль 2" onclick="setStyle2();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Файл csstest.js

```html
function setStyle1()
{
 oTable=document.getElementById("table");
 oTableHead=document.getElementById("tableHead"); 
 oTableFirstLine=document.getElementById("tableFIrstLine");
 oTableSecondLine=document.getElementById("tableSecondLine");

 oTable.className="Table1";
 oTableHead.className="TableHead1";
 oTableFirstLine.className="TableContent1";
 oTableSecondLine.className="TableContent1";
}


function setStyle2()
{
 oTable=document.getElementById("table");
 oTableHead=document.getElementById("tableHead"); 
 oTableFirstLine=document.getElementById("tableFIrstLine");
 oTableSecondLine=document.getElementById("tableSecondLine");

 oTable.className="Table2";
 oTableHead.className="TableHead2";
 oTableFirstLine.className="TableContent2";
 oTableSecondLine.className="TableContent2";
}
```

Файл styles.css

```html
.Table1{    border: DarkGreen 1px solid;    backgroundcolor: LightGreen;}
.TableHead1
{
 font-family:Verdana,Arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:10pt;
}
.TableConent1
{
 font-family:Verdana,Arial;
 font-size:10pt;
}

.Table2
{
 border:DarkBlue 1px solid;
 background-color: LightBlue;
}

.TableHead2
{
 font-family:Verdana,Arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 10pt;
}

.TableConent2
{
 font-family:Verdana,Arial;
 font-size:10pt;
}
```

Что я сделал не правильно, и как заставить работать пример?

Comment: У вас опечатки. Печатайте внимательнее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table id="table"> // closing "

oTableFirstLine=document.getElementById("tableFirstLine"); // not tableFIrstLine
```

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на опечатки все работает

Comment: @LittleBudda Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.